# NX Check Module Boundaries "CONFIGURED undefined"

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl

I recently updated the following packages and did the necessary migrations:

- @nrwl/js: 15.3.0 --> 18.0.4
- @nrwl/workspace 15.3.0 --> 18.0.4
- nx 15.3.0 --> 18.0.4
- @nx-dotnet/core 1.22.0 -> ^2.2.0

After this, I noticed during builds I've been getting the following messages after each module boundary check

```
    Checking module boundaries for [project name]
    CONFIGURED undefined
```

This didn't start happening until this update. Is there a config that I am missing or something I need to update?

I can't find anyone else with this issue so I'm not sure what's causing this.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

The .nx-dotnet.rc.json file was missing a moduleBoundaries section